# How to follow/unfollow entities in CRM Dynamics programmatically?

Tags: rest, api, dynamics-crm-2011

If CRM Dynamics has REST API for following/unfollowing opportunities?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create an entity record of type "Follow" like you'd create any other record. The follow record's `Owner` is the "follower" and the `Regarding` field points to the record that the owner is following. To "Unfollow" you simply delete this Follow record.

You can even create Follow records in out-of-the-box Processes using the "Create" step.